# Material UI for Jetpack Compose for Web

Tags: kotlin, material-ui, jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-web

I wanted to try out the current state of [Jetpack Compose](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb) for a simple web application (no Android App).
Starting off with the [compose-jb/examples/web-landing](https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-jb/tree/master/examples/web-landing) example, I was wondering, is there already an implementation of **Material Design / Material UI** for Jetpack Compose for Web? And I dont mean combining Compose with React or anything, just Compose for Web.

Answer (score 0):

Compose for Web from Jetbrains, as of right now, is still in the Experimental stage. Material 3 Theme Builder does have a web export. That being said, there is Kobweb which is a web framework that uses Compose and is completely built in Kotlin. Furthermore, I've ported over the Android Color system that allows you to use the Jetpack Compose Theme from Material Theme Builder for your project.

Kobweb has a growing community that can help you get going quickly.

The Kobweb homepage can be found [here](https://kobweb.varabyte.com/).

There is also a discord server dedicated to Kobweb: [discord here](https://discord.gg/UpHqYsHm)